# iOS custom keyboard base?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, swift-extensions, ios-extensions

I need to create a custom keyboard that looks/feels pretty much the same like the system keyboards but is for a language that iOS doesn't have:

- whenever I have to type using the system keyboard, I'm subject to the autocorrect, which not only gives wrong options, but also learns wrong words for that keyboard's language.
- the language I need doesn't use 3 of the 26 Latin letters but it does need diacritics in some others as well as the ' quite often, so it would be nice to repurpose 3 of the keys for that.

My problem is that I'm not interested in creating a keyboard from bare UIViews just to do what in my opinion amount to tweaks to the existing system keyboards. I was dumbstruck when I found out that apparently I do have to recreate the whole experience myself instead of having some Apple-provided basis to build upon. I also can't see most developers being thrilled, so I began to think I may be wrong and there is something we can use after all. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I had the same situation, but ended up creating my own custom keyboard. It is much simpler than your need I guess, but the effort is not that scary. Check the Pod out ![here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftMaterialKeyboard).